# Repairing buggy query server-side – without changes in the app

Tags: sql-server, query, errors

More external apps are accessing our ERP SW database. As we were adding some columns into our structure, some queries from the external app become buggy because they are not specifying the targeted table in the query and errors out with *Ambiguous column name…* message.

The app vendor is inaccesible. We cannot repair the query from the app point nor change our structure (it’s for more customers).

Can we do something at the database server level?

Comment: The most obvious thing would be to make the new columns have a different column name - but maybe it is too late for that? Rename the base table and create 2 views - one with the original name and columns and one with a new name and the additional columns ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible (renaming base table). Imagine, thousands of companies using our ERP SW. For all of them (including this customer) we have deployed structure changes (adding columns to the tables which is part of our "core" and more - we do this in every new version). Vendor app is accesing our "core" tables...Is it more clear now? Thanks...

Comment: Sounds like it is the application vendor who has the problem and not you ? They have written the query without providing table aliases on the assumption there would never be a second column added with the same name.

Comment: As I said, application vendor is inaccesible. Of cource, this is not long term solution. Maybe, I could play a bit with the schemas. Query does not use schemas, just TableName.ColumnName. App is accessing database under dedicated user / login. I could set for them different default schema and make the new object under this schema without ambiguous column. Hopefully SQL Server will point to this new schema...

Comment: Yes.  Creating a schema with views for backwards-compatibility is about all you can do.

Comment: The workaround with default schema and views works. Unfortunately it has some side effects for our SW - but that's another story. I'll put it into my question.

Answer (score -1):

You are facing the error ***Ambiguous column name…*** because the app is quering your database this way:

```
SELECT 
[Name], 
[Salary], 
[Name], 
[Age]
FROM TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
ON A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
```

As you can see there are two `[Name]` in the `SELECT`. You will resolve the issue by recreating the query this way:

```
SELECT 
A.[Name], 
[Salary], 
B.[Name], 
[Age]
FROM TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
ON A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
```

Yes, you are facing this because, as you said, you are adding some columns in your DB. You have 2 choices:

1. Contact the vendor and make it aware of the ***Ambiguous column name…*** error
2. Recreate the structure of your database and avoid using column names that were already used.